# How to Fetch a html form's Post variables using AMPSCRIPT and create a record with the values in salesforce objects

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a html web form which have input fields in it and when a customer fills in the form and clicks on submit, i want the input values to be taken into some data extension in marketing cloud [Marketing cloud and salesforce are connected using marketing cloud connector] and further i want the values to be created as a record inside salesforce using AMPSCRIPT..Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that your 'html web form' is a [CloudPage](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/cloudpages/) or [Landing Page](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/landing_pages/#WhatisaLandingPage), then you can easily achieve this using AMPscript. Refer to sample code below.

Replace `Account` with the SF Object that you are creating records in, and `MyDataExtensionName` with the name of your Data Extension (and update the fields accordingly).

When the form is submitted using my code example, a confirmation message is displayed on the page.

This should be enough to get you started!

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

%%[
var @email, @firstName, @lastName, @createSfRecord, @createDeRecord

set @firstName = RequestParameter('firstName')
set @lastName = RequestParameter('lastName')
set @email = RequestParameter('email')

if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then

   set @createSfRecord = CreateSalesforceObject(
    'Account', 3,
    'FirstName', @firstName,
    'LastName', @lastName,
    'Email', @email)

   set @createDeRecord = InsertDE(
    'MyDataExtensionName',
    'First Name',@firstName,
    'Last Name',@lastName,
    'Email',@email)
endif

]%%

<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
<label>First Name</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName">

<label>Last Name</label>
<input type="text" name="lastName">

<label>Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email">

<input id="submitted" type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

%%=IIF(RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted", '<p>Your form has been submitted.</p>','')=%%

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you :) In the Form tag, which page url must be given? and why is that for? Can you briefly say me

Comment: The page posts back to itself. The `RequestParameter('PAGEURL')` function reloads the page when the form is submitted, posting the form parameters to back the page, which are then retrieved by the `RequestParameter()` functions. Note that I included a hidden `submitted` field, and if this is value present (which it would be after form submit), then this indicates that the form has been submitted and the `if RequestParameter("submitted")...` condition then creates a record in the SF Object and Data Extension. Similarly , the `IIF()` function displays a confirmation message on the page.

Comment: Hi @Priya, did I answer your question? I tested the code before posting, so it should work for you. But let me know if you have issues.

Comment: Hi @Eliot Harper .. In RequestParameter('PAGEURL') i have given the Cloud page url of the same code and the page is getting executed when i paste the url into a browser but when i click on submit after entering firstname,lastname and email, i get 500 - Internal Server Error(Couldnt Figure out why?)

Comment: Hello Priya, you shouldn't need to replace `RequestParameter('PAGEURL')` with the URL, just use the code that I supplied. If you still have issues, then the first thing I would do is either comment out or remove the code from `if RequestParameter...` to `endif`. My guess is that you haven't created the required fields in the DE or you are missing some required fields in your SF Accounts object.

Comment: @priya to debug, paste the code from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/eliotharper/104d3a0e6074b8c149a515e1c94bb9dc) into an email, then validate and preview with a Subscriber record.

Comment: What do you see if you put `<p>%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%</p>` on your page? Hardcoding the page URL as your action should work too. Is this a CloudPage or Landing Page? I tested on a CloudPage,

Comment: Its working.. I Used my cloudpage url inside the request parameter and data extension record is getting created when i submit the form.. but salesforce record is not getting created and shows 500 internal server error

Comment: Good to hear. I'd try creating a record in the SF Sales Cloud UI to determine what fields are required by the Object. Also you need to check that the fields in your AMPscript match the SF field API names and change `3` with the number of fields you are creating.