# Generate leads in Salesforce from ExactTarget Subscriber List

Tags: marketing-cloud, leads, contact

I have recently started working on ExactTarget so please excuse my ignorance. Can anyone guide me on how Can we generate leads or contacts in Salesforce whenever Subscribers are added to a list in ExactTarget?

TIA

Comment: How are you adding Subscribers to a list? Are you manually importing them?

Comment: Hi Eliot, We have setup some microsites forms. Whenever they are filled subscribers are added to a particular list. We want to generate these leads in SF whenever this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using microsite forms to create subscribers, then this is easy to do.

I'm assuming you are already using the AMPscript `RequestParameter()` function to retrieve form field values which you are then using to add subscribers to a list, for example:

```
set @firstName = RequestParameter('FirstName')
set @lastName = RequestParameter('Surname')
set @email = RequestParameter('email')
```

All you need to do is use the [CreateSalesforceObject](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/salesforce/CreateSalesforceObject.html) AMPscript function to create a new record in your SF Lead or Contact object when the form is submitted. For example:

```
set @createSfRecord = CreateSalesforceObject(
 'Account', 3,
 'FirstName', @firstName,
 'LastName', @lastName,
 'Email', @email)
```

A few notes:

1. Replace `Account` with the SF object that you are creating a record in
2. Replace `3` with the number of fields you are inserting in the new record
3. Ensure that the field names, e.g. `FirstName` matches the [API name](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000007594&language=en_US) in the SF object.
4. You will must have the [Marketing Cloud Connector](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/) installed and configured on your account to use the Salesforce AMPscript functions.

Refer to a complete example of using this function in an HTML form in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137608/how-to-fetch-a-html-forms-post-variables-using-ampscript-and-create-a-record-wi#137615).

Comment: Thanks Eliot. I would never have guessed it would be that easy.