# Unable to redirect to error page using redirect function in AMPScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I want to add records into data extension through cloud page.  I'm using `upsertdata` function and also enforcing server side validation in AMPScript

CloudPage:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="https://test...." method="post" name="TestForm">
<input name="First_Name" id="First_Name" type="text" value="">
        <input name="Last_Name" id="Last_Name" type="text" value="">
        <input name="Email" id="Email" type="email" value="">
</form>
  </body>
</html>

%%[
set @FirstName = RequestParameter('First_Name')
set @LastName= RequestParameter('Last_Name')
set @EmailId= RequestParameter('Email')
IF NOT EMPTY(@FirstName) AND NOT EMPTY(@LastName) AND NOT EMPTY(@EmailId) THEN
UpsertData('DE',1,'Email',EmailId,'First_Name',@FirstName,'Last_Name',@LastName)
ELSE
RedirectTo('https://........')
ENDIF
]%%
```

If the above three fields values are blank i want to redirect to some error page which has been declared in else block.  It was not redirecting to that page.  Can you please help on this?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Are the rows getting upserted?

Comment: Did you read the [redirectto()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm) documentation?  It doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: I have used redirect() function but when i publish the page, i m not gettting input form to enter first name , last name and email directly it was redirecting me to error page

Comment: ELSE
redirect(CloudPagesURL(69))
ENDIF]%%

Comment: I have changed the code from ELSE block as below   ELSE
redirect(CloudPagesURL(69))
ENDIF]%%

Comment: AMPScript is a server-side language.  It all gets evalulated before the page is displayed in your browser.  If you're posting to the same page, then you'll need to distinguish between GET and POST so it knows what code block to execute.

Comment: Here's an example: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/137615/5202

Comment: Hi Adam, just i want to redirect to another page i.e. error page in else block. Its not the same page..can you please tell me onething whether it is possible or not..

Answer (score 5):

You should be using the [**redirect()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirect.htm?search_text=redirect) function, not [**redirectto()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/redirectto.htm).