# Get current location with AMPscript or SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I have functionality on a cloud page that depends on the CloudPage URL.
I know how to Requestparameter(), but how do I get the entire URL using AMPscript or SSJS?

Comment: You mean the current cloud page URL?

Comment: Yes, like "subdomain.site.com" or what ever url one would use to access the page:
Had it been "subdomain.site.com?value=yes" I could use RequestParameter("value") to get the query string. But how do I get the complete url? The idea is to use the same code on multiple landing pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> You can get the current page url in AMPscript by using
> `RequestParameter('PageURL')`. This gives you the url dynamically
> without you having to hardcode.

**Reference:** Look at [How to Fetch a html form's Post variables using AMPscript and create a record with the values in salesforce objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/137608/how-to-fetch-a-html-forms-post-variables-using-ampscript-and-create-a-record-wi/137615) specifially @Eliot's answer He is using the below snippet to submit the form to the current page.

```
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
```

You can try debugging your currentURL in the page using inline variables like below.

```
<h1>%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%</h1>
```

Comment: Ohh yes!! I totally had forgotten about this one. It does the trick. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Tove You're welcome. Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to get the URL of current page (with parameters) in SSJS:

```
var url = Platform.Request.RequestURL();
```

Effectively, it's the equivalent of `RequestParameter('PAGEURL')` in AMPscript.